# Refactoring tightly coupled classes when only one side can be changed

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns

Please accept my apologies in advance for the somewhat long-winded question. This is the minimal self-contained example I could come up with... I'm pretty sure there must be some obvious/nice/neat solution to this problem, but I'm currently not able to see it.

Ok, here's the problem: Imagine the following situation (nb. a compileable version of the code is available at http://goo.gl/dhRNex). Suppose

```
struct Thing1 {
public:
  void bar(class Implementation1 &i) {
    i.baz();
  }

  // ...various other methods like bar()
};

struct Thing2 {
public:
  void bar(class Implementation2 &i) {
    i.qux();
  }

  // ...various other methods like bar()
};
```

are given. Unfortunately, these classes are fixed, i.e., can not be changed/refactored.

However, `Implementation1` and `Implementation2` are changeable. These two classes share a lot of similar code, so it seems natural to put the shared code in a common base class. However, the code is dependent the type of `Thing` used, but there is no common base class for `Thing1` and `Thing2`, so it seems also natural to use templates. Thus, I came up with the following solution for the base class

```
template<class T, class S>
struct ImplementationBase {
public:
  S *self;

  void foo() {
    T thing;
    thing.bar(*self);
  }

  // ...lots more shared code like foo()
};
```

and concrete implementations

```
struct Implementation1 : public ImplementationBase<class Thing1, class Implementation1> {
public:
  Implementation1() {
    self = this;
  }

  void baz() {
    std::cout << "Qux!" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct Implementation2 : public ImplementationBase<class Thing2, class Implementation2> {
public:
  Implementation2() {
    self = this;
  }

  void qux() {
    std::cout << "Qux!" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Ideally, one would use `this` instead of `self` in `foo`, but the problem is that `this` is of type `ImplementationBase<class Thing1, class Implementation1>`, but `Implementation1` is required. Obviously, the whole thing is quite a mess and the `Implementation` and `Thing` classes are too tightly coupled, but I cannot see an easy way out without being able to refactor the `Thing` classes. So, finally, my questions are:

1. Is there a better alternative to using the `self` trick above?
2. Is there a design that would solve this problem in a better manner? (I have a feeling, there is, but that I'm missing something obvious)

If you have made it this far, thanks a lot for taking the time and reading the whole story and my apologies again for this long-winded question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already using CRTP so you don't need the self at all:

```
template<class T, class S>
struct ImplementationBase {        
public:
  S* getThis() { return static_cast<S*>(this); }

  void foo() {
    T thing;
    thing.bar(*getThis());
  }

  // ...lots more shared code like foo()
};
```

Comment: No, he doesn't need to inherit from S.  His `Implementation1` and `Implementation2` classes inherit from `ImplementationBase` and pass themselves as template parameters.

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly what I was looking for, I knew I was missing something obvious.